# Create dictionary about given peoples' hobbies as Name: [hobby_1, hobby_2] in Python

Tags: python

how do i go about doing this? Assuming I have a .txt file with that looks like something in the first codeblock below, keeping in mind 1 name might be in the .txt file more than one time so for example Jack's hobbies are crafting as well as skateboarding.

```
Jack:crafting
Peter:hiking
Wendy:gaming
Monica:tennis
Chris:origami
Sophie:sport
Monica:design
Carmen:sport
Chris:sport
Monica:skateboarding
Carmen:cooking
Wendy:photography
Monica:tennis
Cooper:yoga
Wendy:sport
Cooper:movies
Monica:theatre
Cooper:yoga
Chris:gaming
Molly:fishing
Jack:skateboarding
```

Code

```
def create_dictionary(file):
    """
    Create dictionary about given peoples' hobbies as Name: [hobby_1, hobby_2].

    :param file: original file path
    :return: dict
    """
    dct = {}
        with open(file, encoding='utf-8') as file:
             for line in file:
                 ???
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple way  of doing this without any libraries :

```
hobbies_dict = {}
with open('hobbies.txt', encoding='utf-8') as file:
  for line in file:
    #key = line.split(':')[0].strip()
    #val = line.split(':')[1].strip()
    key, val = line.rstrip().split(':')

    if key in hobbies_dict.keys() and val not in hobbies_dict[key]:
      hobbies_dict[key].append(val)
    else:
      hobbies_dict[key] = [val]

print(hobbies_dict)
```

Comment: You are needlessly performing the split twice. You can use `key, val = line.split(':')` to perform it only once.

Comment: Also there are 2 mutex conditions checks.  `if key not in hobbies_dict.keys()` is `False`, it is clear that `elif key in hobbies_dict.keys()` will be `True`. This can be changed to `else`

Comment: Thank you, is there a way to skip duplicate hobbies for a person aswell? I forgot to mention in the OP.

Comment: yes i have updated the answer .it will avoid duplicates

Answer (score 3):

You may a `defaultdict` with a `list` as factory, if the key is not present it initialize the mapping with a `list` so you can directly `append`

```
from collections import defaultdict

def create_dictionary(file):
    dct = defaultdict(set)
    with open(file, encoding='utf-8') as file:
        for line in file:
            name, hobby = line.rstrip().split(":")
            dct[name].add(hobby)
    return dct
    # return {k: list(v) for k, v in dct.items()} if for later you need values to be list
```

Returning

```
{
    "Jack":   ["crafting","skateboarding"],
    "Peter":  ["hiking"],
    "Wendy":  ["gaming","photography","sport"],
    "Monica": ["tennis","design","skateboarding","tennis","theatre"],
    "Chris":  ["origami","sport","gaming"],
    "Sophie": ["sport"],
    "Carmen": ["sport","cooking"],
    "Cooper": ["yoga","movies","yoga"],
    "Molly":  ["fishing"]
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to skip duplicates? In your return yoga is listed twice under values.

Comment: @Crimson yes, use a `set`, then you can come back to a list if needed

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code you are looking for:

```
def create_dictionary(file):
"""
Create dictionary about given peoples' hobbies as Name: [hobby_1, hobby_2].

:param file: original file path
:return: dict
"""
dct = {}
with open(file, "r", encoding='utf-8') as file:
        for line in file:
            # First strip the unwanted characters and split the line at :
            d = line.strip().split(":")

            # Check whether there are 2 components in the given line and proceed
            if(len(d) > 1):
                # Check whether user already in the dictionary.
                if(d[0] in dct):
                    # User exist append the hobby.
                    dct[ d[0] ].append( d[1] )
                else:
                    # User not exist create a new element in dct.
                    dct[ d[0] ] = [ d[1] ]

return dct


print(create_dictionary("input.txt"))
```